# How can I make a selection in the shape of text with a given font in GIMP 2?

Tags: gimp

I'm trying to design a logo for my band. My idea is to have a fraction of a scenic image be duplicated in the shape of some text (my album name). I can't figure out how to do this.

[image: Kinda like this.]

Like that, but with text, not rectangles. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. On your text layer, *right click → Text to path.*
2. On your text work space, *right click → Select → From Path.* Now you have the selection on the text.
3. Choose your background layer as active layer, then copy your selection (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>).
4. Paste the selection on new layer. *Edit → Paste as → New layer.*

Comment: You can replace 1+2 by just Layer>Transparency>Alpha to selection (or same item in the right-click menu).

Comment: Oh my gosh, thank you! You're a lifesaver. I'd upvote but I don't have enough reputation.